# ember.js - Mix resource routes with plain routes for non standard nested layout

Tags: view, ember.js, nested-routes

I want the following layout: [image]

So when at `/courses` I display all courses in a screen-wide template, however when a user navigates to a course e.g. `/courses/2`, it then becomes a nested view with the list of courses on the left hand side and the course detail page in the main area.

I tried the following setup but can't get it to work:

```
this.resource('courses', function() {
    this.resource('course', { path: '/:course_id' });
});
this.route('allcourses', {path: '/courses'});
```

with the following route definitions:

```
App.AllcoursesRoute = App.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('course');
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('allcourses', {
      into: 'application'
    })
  }
});

App.CoursesRoute = App.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('allcourses');
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('courses', {
      into: 'application'
    })
  }
});

App.CourseRoute = App.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('course', params.course_id);
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('course', {
      into: 'courses'
    });
  }
});
```

Currently I am getting the 'allcourses' template when at /courses however clicking on each course link tries to render the course template into an outlet in the allcourses template rather than the courses template which is what I want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

and what about changing your routes ?

```
this.resource('courses');
this.resource('course', { path: '/courses/:course_id' });
this.route('allcourses', { path: '/courses' });
```

Answer (score 0):

both `courses` and `allcourses` have the same path, that behavior is undefined, and probably confusing ember into thinking you are already in the route.

```
this.resource('courses', function() {  // this defaults to /courses
    this.resource('course', { path: '/:course_id' });
});
this.route('allcourses', {path: '/courses'});
```

Comment: Yeh, I wanted to clobber the usual courses route with the allcourses template, but then fall back to the usual courses template once at the /courses/:id route. Doesn't seem like its possible without defining a new url for 'allcourses'

Comment: I'm torn between saying very defined routes or black magic ui based on which route you're in. (like the comment in edpaez answer)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind kingpin2k's answer and removing the `allcourses` route:

What about using the `CoursesIndexRoute` to show the 'wide' template of all courses. 
And using `CourseRoute` to show both the side bar of all courses (using the content and controller from its parent route) and the course details.

```
App.CourseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  renderTemplate: function() {
    //the main content
    this.render('course', {
      outlet: 'course',
    });
    // the sidebar
    var controller = this.controllerFor('courses');
    this.render('side-bar', {
      into: 'courses',
      outlet: 'side-bar',
      controller: controller
    });
  }

});
```

You may have to use different outlets for displaying the wide template, the sidebar and the details.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I like this idea, and you could just show/hide the side bar (from the courses route) based on the route